# Cloud Firestore: Problem with rules for my Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here are my current Cloud Firestore rules: https://pastebin.com/rQBacfLm

In this screenshot you can see my current database structure:

[image: In this screenshot you can see my current database structure.]

Here is the code from my Flutter app with which I am trying to get a stream of the boats in which "owner" equals the users UID:

```
_databaseReference.collection("boats").where("owner", isEqualTo: "My UID").snapshots()
```

I have no idea whether there is a general fault in the rules or whether it has something to do with the stream. I think it might be a problem with the rules, but I don't know what is wrong. Can someone spot an error in the rules?

This is the log from the console:

```
W/Firestore(26299): (22.0.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(boats where owner == # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@628107b8
W/Firestore(26299): integer_value: 0
W/Firestore(26299): string_value: "My UID" order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore(26299): (22.0.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(boats where share array_contains # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@628107b8
W/Firestore(26299): integer_value: 0
W/Firestore(26299): string_value: "My UID" order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

**Important information: "My UID" is just a placeholder, in reality there is my real UID. That is not the problem!**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can see in my Firestore rules (https://pastebin.com/rQBacfLm), these are the conditions for accessing documents from the `boats` collection:

```
match /boats/{boat} {
  allow create: if isUser(database);
  allow read, update: if isUser(database) && isShared(boat, database);
  allow read, update, delete: if isUser(database) && isOwner(boat, database);
}
```

When I now execute `_databaseReference.collection("boats").where("owner", isEqualTo: "My UID")`, I get a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error, because `where` needs the permission `list`, which is included in the permission `read`, but the `read` permission is only given for boats for which `isShared` is `true`. Therefore the `list` permission needs to be added to the line `allow create`, so that the app can search for the boats the user owns (`.where("owner", isEqualTo: "My UID")`).

Comment: I saw that my answer to my own question got a downvote. What is the criticism about the answer? Is there anything wrong with it? Since I use "list" in my rules, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You allow to read boat document if

```
    function isOwner(boatId, db) {
      return get(/databases/$(db)/documents/boats/$(boatId)).data.owner == request.auth.uid;
    }
```

Owner field equals user authentication id. But at screenshot of your document its value `My UID` which i believe is not valid id from which you are doing query. Check if problem here

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I intentionally put that as a placeholder wherever my UID is. In reality there is my UID.